# setGeneric for a list of objects

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I have the following function:

```
myFunction = function(objects,params) {
  for (i in 1:length(objects)) {
     object = objects[[i]]
     object = myOtherFunction(objects, params)
     objects[[i]] = object
  }
 return (objects)
}
#' @rdname myFunction
#' @aliases myFunction
setMethod("myFunction", signature(object ="list"), myFunction)
```

How can I properly set the `setMethod()` and `setGeneric()` methods to accept a list of objects of a given type, let's say a list of objects of type `SingleCellExperiment` ?

Comment: There is a validation option for S4 methods. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html and searrch for "Checking validity".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write different methods to handle lists of class `foo` and lists of class `bar` then S4 will need some help, since both objects are of class `list` and hence the same method will be called in both cases.

There are a few options:

- firstly, do you need to use lists at all? Don't forget all the base types in R are vectors, so for simple classes like

  `setClass("cuboid",slots=list(
    height="numeric",
    width="numeric",
    depth="numeric"
  )) -> cuboid`

if you want to represent a set of multiple cuboids you don't need to use a list at all, just feed vectors of values to `cuboid`. This doesn't work as well for more exotic classes, though.

- alternatively, you can write a `list` method with some extra logic to determine which lower-order method to dispatch. You should also think about what to do if the list contains objects of multiple different classes.
- in some situations you might be able to use either `lapply` or a function that takes arbitrary numbers of arguments via `...`. In the latter case you may be able to make use of `dotsMethods` (check the help page on that topic for more info).

If you want to write a method that will only be called on lists of objects of class `foo` and there may exist another method that wants to operate on lists, then you can either:

- write a method for class `foo` directly, and then use `sapply` or `lapply` rather than calling your function on the list
- write a method for class `list` that checks whether the list has `foo`s in it and if it doesn't, calls `nextMethod`.